# How to get IMEI in android 10

Tags: android, android-security

For security purposes, I want to store the IMEI number of app users but I am getting the following error

```
2020-02-14 13:29:36.620 14794-14794/com.udaan.android.creditoperations E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.udaan.android.creditoperations, PID: 14794
    java.lang.SecurityException: getImeiForSlot: The user 10643 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getImeiForSlot(ITelephony.java:10471)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getImei(TelephonyManager.java:1754)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getImei(TelephonyManager.java:1715)
```

Is there any way to access IMEI number including latest android devices?

Comment: After Q - no. Why do you want the IMEI perhaps we can offer an alternative?

Comment: @Blundell This is to ensure if the same account is logged in from 2 people we can find those. Basically, the application is closely circulated and there are high chances of fraud if two people are using the same login.

Comment: If you have them login, can't you use that as the identifier? (the fact they are logged into account X)

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Android 10, Third-party apps installed from the Google Play Store cannot get IMEI number. 
That's why you are getting this Security Exception.

I would suggest you use any other unique id for your purpose. For best practices of unique identifiers recommended by Google, you can check out the below link

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Answer (score 1):

From Android 10, there is no way to get it. Find an alternative unique identifier from document which shared by Abhishek.

*Starting in Android 10, apps must have the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE privileged permission in order to access the device's non-resettable identifiers, which include both IMEI and serial number.*

Caution: Third-party apps installed from the Google Play Store cannot declare privileged permissions.

More details;

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add permission to AndroidManifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```